Invalid opcode in Metamask and Ganache
When running a contract I am getting in remix an invalid opcode as well on Metamask, the contract that I am running is quite simple:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract WebsiteStorage {
    string private storedWebsite;

    function setWebsite(string calldata url) public {
        storedWebsite = url;
    }

    function getWebsite() public view returns (string memory) {
        return storedWebsite;
    }
}

How to solve it?
I have tried to check the connection between Ganache and Metamask and the network was 100% working.
I have checked the Ganache logs and same error was mentioned but the contract was found in the contracts section.
I have tried tried to check the connection between Remix and Metamask, the connection is working properly as I have found the logs of the transactions posted from Remix on Metamask logs.

Thanks.
Issue Solved, just need to match the same version between remix and ganache.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
